# Definition of Dirichlet characters

Tags: number-theory

The following is the definition of Dirichlet characters given in the book Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Apostol:

[image]

This is confusing to me because I think the $k$ is not uniquely determined. For example, the principal character modulo $2$ is the same as that modulo $4$. So one may not speak of "the" modulus of a Dirichlet character but rather "a" modulus? Am I correct?

Comment: Usually, you define “the” modulus when you define a Dirichlet character (you say “let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character mod $n$“, for instance, or even give an explicit definition in terms of residue classes mod $n$). But this indeed needn’t be the smallest modulus for which such a character could be defined. This quantity is the *conductor* of the Dirichlet character and is important in many situations.

Comment: @Mindlack Yes, except that $\chi(n)=1$ has modulus and conductor $1$ whereas $\chi(n)=1_{\gcd(n,2)=1}$ has conductor $1$ and modulus $2^m$ for any $m\ge 1$. Moreover $\chi(n)=1_{\gcd(n,2)=1} (-1)^{(n-1)/2}$ is a primitive character, modulus $2^m,m\ge 2$, of conductor $4$.. Most books are ambiguous about this but I don't see any alternative viewpoint.

Comment: @reuns $\chi(n)=1_{\gcd(n,2)=1}$ has conductor 1? I thought its conductor is 2.

Comment: It comes from the primitive character $\chi(n)=1$ which is $1$-periodic, thus yes conductor $1$. The periods are the even integers, but it is non-zero iff $\gcd(n,2^m)=1$ thus the modulus are any powers of $2$.